How can I get the deployment id at runtime of a cloudflare worker
I have a cloudflare worker implemented in javascript and want to get the deployment id (the same as shown in the cloudflare ui). I need this code for generating a cacheKey which changes after a software update. Otherwise I regularly have crashes because of incompatible cache data.
 wrangler deploy cloudflarewrapper.js
 ⛅️ wrangler 3.0.1 (update available 3.78.11)
-------------------------------------------------------
Total Upload: 1873.17 KiB / gzip: 278.74 KiB
Uploaded myscript (4.90 sec)
Published myscript (1.40 sec)
  https://myscript.xx.workers.dev
Current Deployment ID: 506d732c-7cda-11ef-ba53-136088c204d0
                       ^^^^^^^^

I want this part or the full uuid. the same id is also used in the dashboard, statistics and logs
export default {
  async fetch(request, env, ctx) {
    const cacheUrl = new URL(request.url);

    // Construct the cache key from the cache URL
    const cacheKey = new Request(cacheUrl.toString() + currentActiveVersion, request);
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


I don't see anything in the docs about being able to access the deployment id. Are you using CI/CD, like Github Actions, to deploy? If so, I'd probably just make an environment variable that is populated from the commit hash. You'll at least be able to pair the log information with the commit.

I just found this: https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/bindings/version-metadata/. It's tagged with "beta" and the shown wrangler.toml configuration produces: Unexpected fields found in top-level field: "version_metadata"

Finally, I found it. There's the documentation page https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/bindings/version-metadata/ which handles exactly this scenario.
What made my first tests failing, was an old version of wrangler. This feature is quite new (and still beta), so you probably have to update wrangler first. Version 3.78.12 was good for me:
npm install wrangler --save-dev

Then, add these two lines to your wrangler.toml:
[version_metadata]
binding = "CF_VERSION_METADATA"

And use the following code:
export default {
  async fetch(request, env, ctx) {
    const { id: versionId, tag: versionTag, timestamp: versionTimestamp } = env.CF_VERSION_METADATA;
    console.log(versionId);

btw versionId contains the complete UUID. The dashboard of cloudflare only shows the first segment of if.
